# Beyond Basic: Help finding Preferences Tab in Cloud9

Tags: preferences, cloud9

I'm trying to get to project settings to set tabs & cannot find a Preferences or Project Settings area to do so. All AWS instructions to change user settings say "On a menu bar, choose AWS Cloud9, Preferences..." " ...on the Preferences Tab in the side navigation pane". I can find no menu in the dashboard nor IDE for this (only a few areas that say preference but are just for light/dark theme or # of cards visible).

I saw one previous question on here similar to this and as of Feb '20 that user found the project settings in an EC2 settings area- I've tried that but still cannot find project settings or preferences to change my user settings. (If its relevant, I'm using Chrome on a windows 10 machine)

thanks

UPDATE: This is what I see: [IDE lacks menu bar/cog with project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aajgL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that happens to anyone else- the solution that worked for me was to create a new environment- The new environment showed up with a menu bar/cog in the top right corner. I deleted the old environment and problem solved (though I have no idea how I got an IDE w/no menu in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

In the top right corner, you should see a cog in the top right, this is project settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately mine doesn't look anything like that :/ I just added a screenshot to my original posting. I dont have that menu bar at the top at all, and my cog doesn't have a project settings :/  Have any idea why or how I can get to a similar view as yours?